# Problem : PyQt5 QMessageBox on the foreground

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a problem when i'm trying to pop up a QMessageBox, with Pyqt5 Python 3.5 
It is in the background not foreground. 
I have tried different read on this forum, without success. 
This QMessage is called when I click on the Save Button

My all code:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog,QMessageBox
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.exporters


class Ui_Viewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        super(Ui_Viewer, self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def createWindow(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Viewer")
        self.resize(1280, 960)
        self.Button_Save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.central_widget)
        self.Button_Save.setGeometry(10, 10, 70, 30)
        self.Button_Save.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(109, 109, 109);")
        self.Button_Save.setText("Save")
        self.Button_Save.clicked.connect(self.process_Save_Figure)

    def process_Save_Figure(self):
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        msgBox.warning(msgBox.setStyleSheet("background-color:gray;"), 'Information',
                       "Save Data")

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_Viewer()
    MainWindow.createWindow()
    MainWindow.show()

    rc = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(rc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you want to customise a message-box, don't use the static methods like `warning()`, because they will create an separate, internal instance of `QMessageBox` which you cannot access. You need to [use the propery-based API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#the-property-based-api) to explicitly set all the options, and then show the dialog with `exec()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
  def process_Save_Figure(self):
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.warning(self, 'Information',"Save Data")
```

if it's works you can apply your style.

Comment: Hello Tsifi , 

Your method's work correctly. Of course. 
Nevertheless, I can change my style of my messagebox. 
It inherits of style of my parent...

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappears when I comment out the line `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`

(tested on PySide2)

Comment: Hy 7t7 Studios , 

Thank you. 
Nevertheless, if i apply your method, my first windows is killed :(